# Chrome Extensions - How to check if its a specific page ( Popup, Options, Devtools, Background, ContentScript )?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, web-extension

I am working on a library which needs to be called & executed in the background script only. How to check if the library is being executed in background script only ?

- So, something like this :..

```
const isBackgroundScript = checkForBackgroundScript();
if (!isBackgroundScript) {
   throw new Error(`xyz function can only be called from background script`); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManifestV3 background script is a service worker:

```js
const isBackgroundScript = typeof ServiceWorkerGlobalScope === 'function';
```

ManifestV2:

```js
const isBackgroundScript = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() === window;
```